# Why does setInterval works in useEffect but not when inside functional component context (see inside if condition)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was building UI for a dictionary that shows a word followed by its meaning. The word switches through a **`setInterval`**. In the below code I'm setting up the **`setInterval`** initially and then on some events. Here I'm just focused on the initial **`setInterval`**.

Although I'm quite experienced in React I am still not able to grab my head around why the **`setInterval`** works when inside **`useEffect`** hook but not from the if condition.

To replicate just comment out the if condition and uncomment **`useEffect`** block.

Can someone please explain?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Dictionary from './Dictionary.json';
import './App.css';

const words = Object.keys(Dictionary);
let currentInterval;

function App() {
  const [randomWord, setRandomWord] = useState(words && words[Math.round(Math.random() * words.length)]);
  const [wordGenerationDuration, setWordGenerationDuration] = useState(10000);

  function selectRandomWord() {
    setRandomWord(words[Math.round(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))]);
  }
  
  if(!currentInterval) {
    currentInterval = setInterval(selectRandomWord, wordGenerationDuration);
  }

  // useEffect(
  //   () => {
  //     currentInterval = setInterval(selectRandomWord, wordGenerationDuration);
  //   }, []
  // )


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='dictionary-wrapper'>
        <p className='dictionary-word'>
          {randomWord}
        </p>
        <p className='dictionary-meaning'>
          {Dictionary[randomWord]}
        </p>
        <p className='next-button cursor-pointer'>
          <span
            onClick={
              () => {
                clearInterval(currentInterval);
                selectRandomWord();
                currentInterval = setInterval(selectRandomWord, wordGenerationDuration);
              }
            }
          >
            Next Word
          </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <span>Auto Switch Duration:</span>
          <input
            className='dictionary-input'
            type='number'
            placeholder={wordGenerationDuration / 1000}
            onChange={
              (evt) => {
                const wordGenerationDuration = Math.max(evt.target?.value * 1000, 10000);
                clearInterval(currentInterval);
                setWordGenerationDuration(wordGenerationDuration);
                currentInterval = setInterval(selectRandomWord, wordGenerationDuration);
              }
            }
            min='10'
          />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How exactly does it _not_ work?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your original interval callback is a function defined within your component (`selectRandomWord`).

When your component re-renders, the `currentInterval` will be set so your interval will not be redefined. The existing interval will then refer to the previous render's version of `selectRandomWord` which is no longer updating the state of the current render.

What you should really do is

1. Store the interval hook in a ref
2. Register your interval within `useEffect()`, and
3. Make sure you clear the interval in the component cleanup

```js
function App() {
  const interval = useRef()
  const [randomWord, setRandomWord] = useState(words && words[Math.round(Math.random() * words.length)]);
  const [wordGenerationDuration, setWordGenerationDuration] = useState(10000);

  function selectRandomWord() {
    setRandomWord(words[Math.round(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval.current) {
      interval.current = setInterval(selectRandomWord, wordGenerationDuration)
    }

    // cleanup
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current)
    }
  }, [])
```

You can also clear the interval at any time using

```js
clearInterval(interval.current)
```

See also https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: Thanks Phil for the response, Just so I am getting this right (and this is the only thing making sense to me), does a new **`setRandomWord`** setter function getting created every time the component is re-rendering?

Comment: No, the state setter is not redefined since it's a _hook_. What is redefined is `selectRandomWord`

Comment: Phil, Then I am not able to get why if the function `setRandomWord` is the same throughout all re-renders and I am passing it a new word every time (computing word every time I am calling the function `words[Math.round(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))]`), It is still not able to update state.

Comment: @yogeshdhiman me too actually. I was trying to put together an example demonstrating the problem but haven't had time today

Comment: Sure Phil, Although I am quite experienced I am unable to wrap my head around this, The only explanation I can think of is listed in my first comment...